# How to pass data from the feature file to step definition file using regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, cucumber

This project is using NodeJS, Cucumber, Gherkin, Selenium.

I am trying to pass either a stored value or for now, a value in this example it would be a URL from the feature file into the step definitions file through the usage of regular expressions.

An example of a feature i would like to use (< url > is my guess-work which i've seen in other examples, which doesnt seem to work)

```
Scenario: 0 | A User Logging In
Given I open the page with the <url>
```

And then also my step definitions file

```
Given("/^I open the page with the url? (.*)$/"), function(next){

    driver.get("http://localhost:3000/login");
    pageElement = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
    pageElement.sendKeys("example@email.co.uk");
    next(); 
};
```

I believe my step definitions file is correct however i'm not positive.

If you need any more information about my project please let me know i am active throughout the day on stack-overflow and aim to have this working quickly.

Thank you in advance for any support,
Jack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try changing the regular expression in your JavaScript to a string that expects the variables you're passing into the `Given` statement:

```
Given('I open the page with the url {string}'), function(next) {
  //your code
}
```

You can define variables in the Gherkin `Given` statements by stating them as they would be presented typically. For example, if you wanted to pass in a `string`:

```
Scenario: 0 | A User Logging In
Given I open the page with the url "http://localhost"
```

Would pass in the variable `url` to your javascript file and contain the string `http://localhost`

Same goes for integers:

```
Scenario: 0 | A User Logging In
Given I open the page with the url "http://localhost" and port 3000
```

Your javascript function will now receive 2 variables, `url` and `port`. Logging them to the console, you will see

```
http://localhost
3000
```

So I would re-arrange your code to look like the following:

Gherkin:

```
Scenario: 0 | A User Logging In
Given I open the page with the url "http://localhost:3000/login"
```

JavaScript:

```
Given('I open the page with the url {string}', (url, next) => {
     console.log(url) // log to check the variable is being passed into the function

     driver.get(url);

     pageElement = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
     pageElement.sendKeys("example@email.co.uk");

     next(); 
});
```

EDIT:
You can find all the documentation on this particular issue [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions#readme).

Comment: This is working, thank you for your help it is much appreciated @blueprintChris

Answer (score 0):

A short answer below- May be useful for upcoming visitors!

The universal RegEx pattern works for all types of data in cucumber is- `([^"]*)`
This is how it will go with complete step def-

```
@Given("^I open the page with the ([^"]*)$") //See note below *
public void yourMethodName(yourdatatType yourDataVar) {

 Your Method(s) implementation using (yourDataVar)
...

}

// * Note- '^' and '$'  symbols will be added automatically by cucumber in the beginning and end of any step definition respectively.
```